# Netbeans/Tomcat/Jersey loading Spring context twice

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, netbeans, jersey

Jersey/Spring application debugged inside Netbeans and deployed to Netbean's Tomcat server has its application context loaded twice. It is loaded, unloaded, and loaded again.

BLOODY WHY?!?!

EDIT: It looks like if I comment out the servlet and servlet-mapping in web.xml, the application context is still loaded twice! If I delete /conf/web.xml file, it is STILL loaded twice. #@@$@! Netbeans/Tomcat

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.PostReplaceFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

Tomcat output:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\adubi_000\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.27.0_base"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.27"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\adubi_000\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.27.0_base\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.27\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.27\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Listening for transport dt_shmem at address: tomcat_shared_memory_id
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 821 ms
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\adubi_000\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\adubi_000\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:26 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:26 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Sep 15 21:19:26 EST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:26 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:27 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2829abfd: defining beans [...]; root of factory hierarchy
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:28 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:28 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.6.Final}
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:28 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:28 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:28 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:28 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/...
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:28 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:28 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:28 PM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog <clinit>
INFO: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:28 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.1 [built 16-January-2007 14:46:42; debug? true; trace: 10]
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:29 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool...
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:29 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:29 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:29 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
...
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:31 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4806 ms
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8866 ms
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:31 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet getContext
INFO: Using default applicationContext
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:31 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, ...
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:31 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.13 06/29/2012 05:14 PM'
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:32 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Sep 15 21:19:26 EST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:32 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2829abfd: defining beans [...]; root of factory hierarchy
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@911a094]) and a value of type [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class javax.xml.bind.annotation.W3CDomHandler=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@64455932}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context []
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\adubi_000\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\apache-tomcat-7.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:36 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:36 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Sep 15 21:19:36 EST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:36 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:37 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6b63d42f: defining beans [...]; root of factory hierarchy
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:37 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:37 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.6.Final}
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:37 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:37 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:38 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:38 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/....
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:38 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:38 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:38 PM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog <clinit>
INFO: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:38 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.1 [built 16-January-2007 14:46:42; debug? true; trace: 10]
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:38 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... 
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:38 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:38 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:38 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:38 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:39 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
...
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:40 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4264 ms
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:40 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase start
INFO: The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:41 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet getContext
INFO: Using default applicationContext
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:41 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, ...
Sep 15, 2012 9:19:41 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.13 06/29/2012 05:14 PM'
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the work of Netbean's maven deploy plugin, which waits for tomcat to start (and load the application as specified in Netbeans-generared ROOT.xml) then tells it to reload it (from a different temporary XML).

A workaround is to edit %CATALINA_BASE%/conf/tomcat-users.xml and change the password of user 'ide' (through which netbeans controls tomcat). Tomcat still loads fine, but deploy-on-save and probably other features won't work.

I'll try looking at the source code of netbeans to see if a better solution is available.  This behavior of the deploy plugin is just bizare. Surely it could start Tomcat empty, and then load the app as it's doing in the second step.

Comment: any solution to this ? I've got a hibernate project and spring context does not seem to be load the transaction the first time but it does the second time. Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: no. I opened a bug but no one's addressed it https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=223035 Regarding transactions, I don't know.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for that. Guess I will just ignore it. I just have to keep deleting my {context name}.xml file from Catalina/localhost folder every time I redeploy. This won't be a problem in production.